# native advertising SDK for xbox

Tags: video, ads, xbox

I am researching the solution / possibility to deliver video ads to xbox app/game. The idea is to develop a SDK that publisher can integrate the SDK into their xbox app/game for advertising, similar to integrating AdMob SDK to iOS and Android apps.

Is this technically possible? Does Microsoft allow 3rd party Advertising SDK; or publisher can only use Microsoft own Advertising SDK.

I google around, haven't found any AdNetwork provides advertising SDK for xbox yet.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes this is *possible* however, Microsoft is not keen on having advertisements used in games, furthermore, in order to update the in-game ads (depending on what types of ads you were thinking of and where they would be placed) there would have to be a way to update these ads. This means you must have the game, in some way, pulling data from a server (not a big deal) but this would open up the game to possible exploits and being that xbox live is paid for, people do not take kindly to advertisements.